# Is php's datetime class reliable when the server is in a daylight savings time area?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have read that php's datetime class relies on the servers clock when generating new date time objects.  Let's say the server is in a location that observes daylight savings time and it's time zone is properly configured.  Can we trust the date time objects that are created during this one hour transition or should we always configure server time to UTC?

Comment: If the server is time zone aware, it's bound to be DST aware as well. The two go hand in hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can trust it. It uses the timezone information from the OS.